# how to fill each Column in datatable

Tags: c#

I am  iterating on a lot of strings and I want to fill my first(and only) 3 Columns with each result and then start again in a new row. like:

```
A     |  B     | C
------+--------+------
"DOG" | "CAT"  | "FISH"    
"FDF" | "AAA"  | "RRR"
```

AND SO ON....
Basically after each row is "full" open new row.

```
HtmlNodeCollection tables = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//table");
HtmlNodeCollection rows = tables[2].SelectNodes(".//tr");

DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
dataTable.Columns.Add("A", typeof(string));
dataTable.Columns.Add("B", typeof(string));
dataTable.Columns.Add("C", typeof(string))
```

Comment: I don't see any code in your snippet that would even attempt what you're trying to attempt.  Can you post an example of what your have tried so far?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use Linq's `GroupBy` to split the long list into groups of 3:

sample-data:

```
DataTable table = new DataTable();
table.Columns.Add("Col1");
table.Columns.Add("Col2");
table.Columns.Add("Col3");

List<string> longList = Enumerable.Range(1, 99).Select(i => "row " + i).ToList();
```

group the long list into parts of three:

```
var groupsWithThree = longList
    .Select((s, i) => new { Str = s, Index = i })
    .GroupBy(x => x.Index / 3);
```

add them to the table:

```
foreach (var group3 in groupsWithThree)
    table.Rows.Add(group3.First().Str, group3.ElementAt(1).Str, group3.Last().Str);
```

Note that it presumes that the list is divisible by three.

Answer (score 4):

try like this

```
 for (int i = 0; i < rows .Count(); i++)
            {

                DataRow datarowObj= dataTable .NewRow();
                datarowObj["A"] = yourValue;
                datarowObj["B"] = yourValue;
                datarowObj["C"] = yourValue;
                dataTable.Rows.Add(datarowObj);
            }
```

Comment: This is not what OP wants. He has a long list, say 999 strings. Now he wants to fill the `DataTable`  with 333 rows since it contains 3 columns.

Answer (score 1):

```
dataTable.Rows.Add(new object[] { "A1", "B1", "C1" })

// Alternatively
object[] arr = new object[] { "A2", "B2", "C2" };
dataTable.Rows.Add(arr);
```

Answer (score 1):

Manage with DataRoxw, for instance, after adding an empty DataRow to your DataTable : 
`DataRow row = table.Rows[0];
    foreach (object item in row.ItemArray)
    {`
 ?