# how to set values in a 2d matrix

Tags: c#

given strings: "a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h", how can i arrange them like so:

```
-1-  -2- -3-    
 "a" "b" "c"  

-1-  -2- -3-  
"d"  "e"  "f"  

-1-  -2- -3-  
"g"  "h"  "df"
```

1,2,3 are the Columns names. (in data table)

Comment: This is not a [real question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/145677/what-is-a-real-question). Please read [faq] and [ask]

Comment: "but i'm a real boy... :*( "

Comment: Did my answer not help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14956177/how-to-fill-each-column-in-datatable

Comment: This is very straight forward stuff. All you need to do is look up a few examples. If you run in to issues in your implementation, show us what you've tried in a new question and we'll be happy to help.

Comment: Do you always have 9 items in your array?  Is the result matrix always going to be 3x3?  If no to either of these, how do you know the dimensions of the result array?  Will it be given as a parameter to a method?  Should it try to determine what it should be based on the data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the Linq approach using `Enumerable.GroupBy`:

```
List<string> strings = new List<string>() { "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h" };
var trios = strings
    .Select((s, i) => new { Str = s, Index = i })
    .GroupBy(x => x.Index / 3);
foreach(var trio in trios){
    var newRow = table.Rows.Add(); // your DataTable here
    newRow.ItemArray = trio.Select(x => x.Str).ToArray();
}
```

This approach works also if the list is **not** divisible by three.

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach (var data in new[] { "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "df" }.Select((s, i) => new { Value = s, Column = i % 3 + 1 }))
{
    Insert(data.Column, data.Value);
}
```